# How to use Tumblr photoset as slideshow?

Tags: jquery, html, css, tumblr

My current code works but only for the first photoset. I want it to work for all the photosets on the blog. Perhaps with `$(this)` but I can't get it to work. Does anyone know how to do this?

My current code:

CSS:

```
<style>
    .slideshow { 
        position: relative; 
        width: 600px; 
        height: 400px; 
        border: 1px solid;
    }
    .slideshow div { 
        position: absolute; 
    }
    .slideshow div img {
        height: 400px !important;
        width: auto;
    }
</style>
```

HTML & JQUERY:

```
{block:Photoset}
    <div class="slideshow">
        {block:Photos}
            <div>
                <img src="{PhotoURL-500}"/>

                {block:Caption}
                    {Caption}
                {/block:Caption}

                {block:Exif}
                    <ul>...</ul>
                {/block:Exif}
            </div>
        {/block:Photos}
        <script>
            $(".slideshow div:gt(0)").hide();

            setInterval(function() { 
                $('.slideshow div:first')
                    .fadeOut(1000)
                    .next()
                    .fadeIn(1000)
                    .end()
                    .appendTo('.slideshow');
            },  3000);
        </script> 
    </div>

    {block:Caption}
        {Caption}
    {/block:Caption}
{/block:Photoset}
```

Comment: Is this code generated for each entry? Could the code block be created multiple times?

Comment: @Twisty   The code between {block:Photoset} and {/block:Photoset} is generated for each post. the code between {block:Photos} and {/block:Photos} is generated for each photo in the photoset